# Smooth Homotopy is an equivalence relation

Tags: homotopy-theory

I want to show that two mappings  $f,g:X \to Y$ are smoothly homotopic is an equivalence relation

We call our map between $f,g$,

$F:X \times [0,1] \to Y$ where $F(x,0)=f(x)$ and $F(x,1) = g(x)$

Reflexivity

$f \sim f$

We define $F(x,t)=f(x) \space \forall x\in X , \forall t\in[0,1]$

Therefore this relation is reflexive.

Transitive

$f \sim g \implies g\sim f$

We define

$F: X \times[0,1] \to Y, F(x,0) = f(x), \space F(x,1) = g(x)$

Let $G: Y\times [0,1] \to X$

$G(x,t) = F(x,1-t)$

Therefore whenever $f \sim g \implies g\sim f$

Finally transitivity is what I don't understand very well

$f\sim g \space \wedge \space g \sim h \implies f \sim h$

My book does this part I just don't understand it

We consider a smooth function $\phi(t): [0,1] \to [0,1]$

Where $\phi(t) = \frac{\lambda(t - \frac{1}{3})}{\lambda(t - \frac{1}{3}) + \lambda(\frac{2}{3} - t)}$
and $\lambda(\tau) = 0$ for $\tau \leq 0, \lambda(\tau) = e^{-\tau^{-1}}$ for $\tau > 0 $

The book says that $\phi(t) = 0$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{3}, \phi(t) = 1$ for $\frac{2}{3} \leq t \leq 1$

Why is this true?

From here we can have $G(x,t) = F(x,\phi(t))$ where $G(x,t)=f(x)$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{3} ,G(x,t)=g(x)$ for $\frac{2}{3} \leq t \leq 1$

There is a similar $H(x,t) = G(x,1-\phi(t))$ where $H(x,t)=g(x)$ for $0 \leq t \leq \frac{1}{3} ,H(x,t)=h(x)$ for $\frac{2}{3} \leq t \leq 1$

$\implies f \sim h$

synopsis

1. How are my reflexive\symmetric arguments
2. How is my transitive argument
3. Why is $\phi =0,1$ for specific $t$

Comment: Well, have you tried just plugging into the definition of $\phi(t)$ when $0\leq t\leq 1/3$ or $2/3\leq t\leq 1$?

Comment: Yea I put in $t=0$. Nonzero $\lambda$ should cancel and when $t=0, \phi(0) = -1$ which isnt in $[0,1]$. Theres something with $\lambda$ that must be happening to make it $0$. I'm not sure what $\tau$ is doing. Seems weird to add all these variables

Comment: $\lambda$ is a function, not a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Okay
2. You need to construct a smooth mapping $K:X\times[0,1]\rightarrow Y$ such that $K(x,0)=f(x)$ and $K(x,1)=h(x)$ using $f\sim g$ and $g\sim h$. With your definitions, $\frac{2}{3}\leq t \leq 1$, $\phi(t)=1$ and $H(x,t)=G(x,0)=F(x,\phi(0))=f(x)$, so it isn't $h$.
3. I suppose you need to notice that, for $\phi$, second term in the denominator is $0$ for $\frac{2}{3}\leq t \leq 1$ so that $\phi(t)=1$. $\phi(t)=0$ for $0\leq t \leq \frac{1}{3}$ as the nominator is $0$.

1*,2*,3* checking smoothness.